# html form not sending ajax request to controler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to use ajax on add to cart form. but it seems that html form not sending any ajax request. 
When I click on the Add to cart button. it show a black page, because i use that ajax check method on controller.

**Controller**

```
 public function addToCart(Request $request){

    $product = Product::find($request->product_id);
    Cart::add($product->id, $product->title, 1, $product->price);

    $response = array(
        'status' => 'success',
        'msg' => 'Setting created successfully',
    );



    if($request->ajax())
        return \Response::json($response);

}
```

**Javascript - AJAX**

```
$('#add').on('submit', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var pid = $('#product_id').val();
     var cat = $('#category_id').val();
     $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: host + '/addToCart',
          data: {product_id: pid, category_id: cat},
          success: function( msg ) {
               $("#xx").append("<div>"+msg+"</div>");
          }
     });
 });
```

**Html Form**

```
<form id="add" action="{{ route('addToCart') }}" method="POST">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="hidden" id="category_id" name="category_id" value="{{ $px->category_id }}">
    <input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="{{ $px->id }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" class="bg-color-input">
</form>
<div id="xx"></div>
```

where did i mistake?

Comment: are you sent the csrf_token with data

Answer (score 0):

if you forget to sent the csrf_token you can solve it as the following:

```
 <form id="add" action="{{ route('addToCart') }}" method="POST">
{{csrf_field()}}
<input type="hidden" id="category_id" name="category_id" value="{{ $px->category_id }}">
<input type="hidden" id="product_id" name="product_id" value="{{ $px->id }}">
<input type="button" id="submitBtn" value="Add to Cart" class="bg-color-input">
</form>
<div id="xx"></div>


 $('document').on('click','#submitBtn',function(){
 e.preventDefault();
 var pid = $('#product_id').val();
 var cat = $('#category_id').val();
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: host + '/addToCart',
      data: {product_id: pid, category_id: cat,'_token','{{csrf_token()}}'},
      success: function( msg ) {
           $("#xx").append("<div>"+msg+"</div>");
      }
 });
});
```

or you can serilize the form:

```
    $('document').on('click','#submitBtn',function(){
   e.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: host + '/addToCart',
      data:$('#add').serialize(),
      success: function( msg ) {
           $("#xx").append("<div>"+msg+"</div>");
      }
 });
 });
```

Comment: it do nothing. not even reloading page

Comment: are you see the console

Comment: to see if the request is sent or not

Comment: SyntaxError: missing : after property id[Learn More] its in console

Comment: or you can share the whole code of page so i can check it